# d3.js timely auto- update via setInterval with jQuery get(json, xml, text, whatever)

Tags: jquery, d3.js

Can anyone help with how to use a jQuery *get*(json, txt, xml, whatever) and setInterval (d3.js) so that I can update my d3 bar chart every N seconds? 
Or does anyone know of an example out there that uses a RESTful *get* to update data through setInterval in d3 SVGs?
I've read [this](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html) tutorial all day, but not clicking with how to incorporate json instead of random walk. 
Many Thanks in advance....

My Unsuccessful Attempt:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title> Testing a d3.js Walking Bar Chart via jQuery getText and d3.js setInterval </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/dev_tests/d3/d3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/dev_tests/latest.jquery/jquery-latest.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div class="body">
          <div class="content">          
            <style type='text/css'>

            .chart {
              margin-left: 42px;
            }

            .chart rect {
              fill: steelblue;
              stroke: white;
            }

            </style>

                <script type='text/javascript'>


                var t = 1297110663,
                    v = 70,
                    data = d3.range(33).map(next1);

                    function next1() {
                    $.get('http://localhost:8080/dev_tests/data/file.txt', function(data1) { 
                        $('.result').text(data1); 
                        alert(data1);
                        return {time: ++t, value: v = data1 };
                            });
                    }
                        var w = 20,
                            h = 80;

                        var x = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([0, 1])
                            .range([0, w]);

                        var y = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([0, 100])
                            .rangeRound([0, h]);

                    </script>

                    <p>Et voila!</p>
                    <script type='text/javascript'>

                    var chart3 = d3.select(".content").append("svg")
                        .attr("class", "chart")
                        .attr("width", w * data.length - 1)
                        .attr("height", h);

                    chart3.append("line")
                        .attr("x1", 0)
                        .attr("x2", w * data.length)
                        .attr("y1", h - .5)
                        .attr("y2", h - .5)
                        .style("stroke", "#000");

                    redraw3();

                        function redraw3() {

                          var rect = chart3.selectAll("rect")
                              .data(data, function(d) { return d.time; });

                          rect.enter().insert("rect", "line")
                              .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i + 1) - .5; })
                              .attr("y", function(d) { return h - y(d.value) - .5; })
                              .attr("width", w)
                              .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
                            .transition()
                              .duration(1000)
                              .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) - .5; });

                          rect.transition()
                              .duration(1000)
                              .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) - .5; });

                          rect.exit().transition()
                              .duration(1000)
                              .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i - 1) - .5; })
                              .remove();

                        }

                        setInterval(function() {
                          data.shift();
                          data.push(data);
                          redraw3();
                        }, 3500);
                        </script>
                </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery's ajax functions are asynchronous, so `next1()` isn't returning anything. You want to:

1. Create your data array
2. Load new data asynchronously
3. Upon loading data, `push()` it onto the data array
4. Redraw your graph

You can simulate this without a JSON call by doing this:

```
var data = [],
    t = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var value = Math.random() * 100;
    data.push({time: ++t, value: value});
    redraw();
}, 1000);
```

And when you get that working, switch to this:

```
var data = [],
    t = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON("path/to/data.json", function(datum) {
        data.push({time: ++t, value: datum});
        redraw();
    });
}, 1000);
```

One problem with this, though, is that if any of the JSON requests take longer than a second you could end up with data loading out of order. So it's best to use `setTimeout()` and queue up the next load only after you're done with the previous one:

```
var data = [],
    t = 0,
    timeout;
function loadNext() {
    $.getJSON("path/to/data.json", function(datum) {
        data.push({time: ++t, value: datum});
        redraw();
        timeout = setTimeout(loadNext, 1000);
    });
}
loadNext();
```

Make sense?

Comment: Shawn, yes this makes perfect sense. Thank you.